# Making invalid method names valid

Tags: ruby

I remember watching a Dave Thomas Ruby tutorial where he used a technique to make invalid method names still acceptable to the interpreter. For example, even though "case date" is an invalid method name since there is a space, in the tutorial his trick allowed that method to still work.

Unfortunately, I don't remember it, but this is my situation. I accept user input and convert it to a method, as shown:

```
def self.define_field(name, type)
  class_eval <<-EOS
    field :#{ name}, type: #{type}
  EOS
end
```

The problem is if there is a space in the user input or another invalid character for a method name, I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
        field :damage date, type: Date
```

How can I can allow for my dynamic method creation, yet allow users to enter any input they want?

Comment: Without knowing what video it was it's hard to say for sure, but you might be talking about using [`method_missing`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing), which is a core part of dynamically programming Ruby. Trying to have `method_missing` catch bad method names could be a very bad practice if the names you create don't meet certain criteria or match certain patterns. The interpreter could spin off into the ozone trying weirder and weird method names as it thrashes if you do it wrong. You could also end up with a really weird vocabulary in your DSL.

Comment: "How can I can allow for my dynamic method creation, yet allow users to enter any input they want?" You need to be careful with this as it sounds like you could run into the same problem as letting them type in anything and then you `exec` it. That's a known attack vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your class `X`, you can generate a symbol that accepts the space character:

```
s = input.to_sym
```

and then call, for example, `define_singleton_method` on your class to define a singleton method:

```
X.define_singleton_method(s) do
    ...
end
```

And then you can use `send` to call that method on a class `X`'s instance `x`:

```
x.send(input.to_sym [, args...])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting `name` to a symbol directly, not through eval.

```
[1] pry(main)> "damage date".to_sym
=> :"damage date"
```

But unless you have a real solid reason to need spaces, I would find another way.  Just seems like a recipe for disaster.

No idea what Dave Thomas was talking about, but I wonder if he was discussing `method_missing`?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing